# Why do my Objects show up black in Cinema-4D?

Tags: 3d, cinema4d

I am new to 3D software and have just started with Cinema 4d. This is a very noobish question but when I create any object in a project it always shows up pitch black.

The tutorial videos I have seen create objects where the faces can be see in a shaded grey. What am I doing wrong?

Image relating to the problem:

[image]

Comment: This normally happens when you have a light in the scene and the light is inside the box such that it can impossibly light the box. But in your screenshot I don't see any lights in your scene, so that's not the case.

Comment: If you click on the object, in the lower right corner basic properties of the cube (like the `Name`, the `Layer`, `Visible in Editor`, etc...) will show up. Can you check if `Use Color` is set to `Off`? If it's set to something else it might be the cause of your colour problem.

Comment: Hi Bart thanks for the response! I have checked the object in question and the Color is set to Off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can either be an issue with OpenGL and you may want to disable it in the program settings (under "File) to test if thats the issue. Or you may have disabled the standard infinite light that is present in every new scene until you add your first light. Add an infinite light from the lights menu and see if that gives your objects some shading.
Also try what @Bart Arondson said and look if you have the "Use Color" option enabled and set to black. If yes set it to "off".

Comment: Hello Paul, thanks for the response! I applied a light and it did show me the faces of the cube. However, what's strange is that when I turned Open GL off like you said, it showed me the cube's faces without the lights. I think its could be a problem with using my integrated graphics on my i7 CPU. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: If you go to `Preferences -> OpenGL -> Show OpenGL Capabilities...` you can see if your graphics card meets Cinema4D's OpenGL requirements.

Comment: OpenGL is important for C4D to show advanced shading. The viewport is very limited in software mode. Always have OpenGL enabled as long as its not causing any problems (which is rather rare anyways). If adding a light shows you a shaded face then the missing infinite light was you problem.

Comment: Hey bart, I just checked the capabilities and the computer seems fine to run it. I have added an infinite light and it seems to work with Open GL on. Thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: in my case when i start the application there is no problem. but when i add light ...and after that i delete that light then the box turns to black.i solved that by unchaking the openGL in preference..but it creates some new problem with materials..adding some extra lines over the applied material.i have updated my graphics card..!

Comment: When you create a light the standard infinite light gets deleted, if you now delete the light you just created you delete all lights in your scene and by that making the scene black. Without OpenGL you dont have any light visualization in the viewport thats why you see your stuff again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I fixed it. All I did was add light layers around my object & it no longer was black.